# Making bash script that copies to new directory and reruns there

Tags: bash

How can I make my bash script not only copy itself to a new directory, but run its copy in the new directory? The relevant part of my current script is as follows:

```
finished=$(tail -2 slurm* | head -1)
today=$(date)

if [[ "${finished}" = "reached required accuracy - stopping structural energy minimisation" ]]
  then
    echo "Job bAl22D3 has finished correctly (CHECK WHICH RUN) on ${today}" >> ~/finished_jobs.txt    
  else
    mkdir nextrun
    cp CONTCAR ./nextrun/POSCAR
    cp INCAR ./nextrun/
    cp KPOINTS ./nextrun/
    cp POTCAR ./nextrun/
    cp runVASP.sh ./nextrun/
    cd nextrun
    sbatch runvasp.sh
fi
```

Everything is created/copied as hoped, but I receive the error:

```
sbatch: error: Unable to open file runvasp.sh
```

The line `sbatch runvasp.sh` is the line for submitting the new job. I am running a structural relaxation in VASP, which has a tendency to time-out. Therefore I have set it to only run a fewer number of steps in a different input file and that is why I am trying to recursively run these smaller jobs.

Any thoughts how/if this is possible?

Comment: At first glance, you are copying `runVASP.sh` but executing `runvasp.sh`. Typo? o.O

Comment: Typo not on here, but in my script :-(  . . . didn't even occur to me, thanks!